# Simple Arduino Code Not Working

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, led

When I upload this code LED at pin 13 goes HIGH and that's it. My goal is to make it blink in the order specified in the array. What am I doing wrong?

```
int Array[] = {1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0};
int Data = 13;
int i = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(Data, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    int x = Array[i];
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(Data, x);
    i = i+1;
    if (i==23) {
        i=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is living your life at a normal speed.

The LED will be blinking, but so fast you can't see it change.

Without adding some delays in there you will just see the LED light up.

Comment: Still not working after i added 200ms delay

Comment: @ArduinoNoob Please don't edit the solution into your question.  Also, if Majenko's answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark underneath the answer's score.